# Why does the graph shows value zero but the value isnt actually zero?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I create a object with x and y axis. Then an array and then plot the data. I know that some of the data from x is duplicated but i think the program sums up the corresponding duplicates in y and shows it.

The data is calculated and shown currently but when i hover the mouse on the bars they show values like 0 or 4 while its clearly not the case. Any suggestions why this happen? You can see the pictures:

Javascript:

```
                var str1 = ["2019", "2018", "2017", "2016", "2015", "2014", "2014"];
                var str = [14, 22, 32, 15, 14, 6,0];

                var trace = {
                x: str1,
                y: str,
                type:'bar'
                };

                var data = [trace];

                var mydiv = document.getElementById('chart');
                Plotly.newPlot(mydiv, data);
```

Pciture from how data looks like:

[image]

[image]

Picture on how the graph looks:

[image]

Comment: The values in your `y` array are strings. It would make more sense if they were numbers.

Comment: @trincot i changed the values of y to numbrs (used: str.map(Number)) and console.log looks currect. The problem still remains tho

Comment: It would be good if you could provide the information needed to reproduce the issue. screenshots of datastructures are not very helpful: provide the actual JavaScript code that creates those.

Comment: @trincot its updated now. the problem is with the duplicted 2014 data. Thats why it shows zero if you recreate the graph and hover on 2014. How can i fix that tho?

Answer (score 0):

As you have identified, the problem is caused by duplicate values in the X-series.

When you have such a duplicate, like here ("2014"):

```
var str1 = ["2019", "2018", "2017", "2016", "2015", "2014", "2014"];
var str = [14, 22, 32, 15, 14, 6,0];
```

Get rid of those, like so:

```
for (let i = str1.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (str1[i] === str[i-1]) {
        str1.splice(i, 1);
        str[i-1] += str[i];
        str.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```